# Hypotheses of the quadratic convergence of a real serie $x_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, second-order-logic

My book claims that a serie has a quadractic convergence if $\forall x_k$, $k = 1, 2, \dots$:
\begin{equation}
    |x-x_{k+1}| \le C|x-x_k|^p
\end{equation}
such as $C \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p = \color{red}2$.

However, it noticed it wasn't that simple: the Newton-Raphson method (used to find roots of a real function $f \in C^1(I \subseteq \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$) for instance which has a quadratic convergence, diverges if the root you are looking for is a double root ($f(x_0) = 0$ such as $f'(x_0) = 0)$.

Here is my question: **What are the complete hypotheses of the quadratic convergence of a real serie $x_k$ ?**

Comment: I think we should not call it quadratic convergence unless it actually converges. E.g. if $C=1$ and $x_k=x+(-1)^k$ then we don't have convergence but we do have $|x-x_{k+1}|\le C|x-x_k|^2.$

Comment: what if I add "$C < 1$" ?

Comment: If $0<C<1$ and $x_k=x+(-1)^k/C$ then $|x-x_{k+1}|=C|x-x_k|^2$ and we still don't have convergence.